# Symfony domCrawler parse html not shown in page source

Tags: php, html, symfony

I believe the question has already been discussed but I could not find the answer. The question is how to get html contents of the page which is not shown when I right-click and select page source in my browser? Also in chrome developer tools when I right click on an element and choose inspect element I can see it in the DOM tree. Example page is (trying to get the list of sites):

http://www.liveinternet.ru/rating/

For getting html contents I use Symfony2 DomCrawler and it gets html perfectly except the cases when it is not present on page source. Thank you.

Thank you

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Have you read your own question after typing it?

Comment: just try to get the source of the above mentioned page (right-click on it and select view source). You will see that there is no list of sites inside it (empty after div id="rows"), although they are present in chrome dev tools if you click on a link and try to inspect element

Answer (score 3):

This is because that content is loaded dynamically using JavaScript. Since the DomCrawler does not execute `<script>` tags, you are unable to crawl any HTML that is not already present on the DOM the moment you load the page.
As an alternative, try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which does execute JavaScript.

Comment: To phrase it another way: The list is filled by javascript. The list is not there as part of the page source, but the javascript that generates the list is there. What you are seeing when you "Inspect element" is not the same as when you view page source.